# Árbol binario de búsqueda

Tags: java

Cree las clases  y tengo código implementado, ya no he podido seguir, el problema es en el método de eliminar ya que quiero eliminar desde el nombre
El creado 4 clases.. clase Nodo, clase para los métodos, clase de datos del paciente, y por ultimo el main .. y el método de presentar inorden también me imprime mal

Si me podrían ayudar explicándome el error, mil gracias enserio

public class ArbolRegistro {

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Nodo raiz;
int cont = 0;

public ArbolRegistro() {
    raiz = null;
}

public boolean arbolVacio() {
    if (raiz == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int menu() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Insertar [1] : ");
    System.out.println("Eliminar[2]");
    System.out.println("Presentar[3]");
    System.out.println("salir[0]");
    System.out.println();
    return sc.nextInt();
}

public Nodo insertar(Nodo X, String names, String telefono, int edad) {
    Paciente p = new Paciente(names, telefono, edad);
    if (X == null) {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(p);
        return nuevo;
    } else {
        if (edad > X.info) {
            X.der = insertar(X.der, names, telefono, edad);
        } else {
            X.izq = insertar(X.izq, names, telefono, edad);
        }
    }
    return X;
}
```

Este metodo reemplaza el valor eneste caso la edad, recorriendo el subarbol izquierdo cuando se elimina un dato, este debe desaparecer y los demas reemplazar los datos q se eliminaron.
En este no se cual es el error por favor me indicarían?

```
public int reemplazar(Nodo actua) {
    Nodo p = actua;
    Nodo a = actua.izq;
    int valor;
    while (a.der != null) {
        p = a;
        a = a.der;
        cont++;
    }
    System.out.println(cont);
    valor = a.info;
    if (p == actua) {
        p.izq = a.izq;
    } else {
        p.der = a.izq;
    }
    return valor;
}

public int cont(int cont) {
    return cont;
}

 
public Nodo eliminar(Nodo actual, String name) {
    if (actual == null) {
        System.out.println("No existe el elemento a eliminar");
    } else {
        if (name == actual.p.names) {
            actual.der = eliminar(actual.der, name);
        } else if (name == actual.p.names) {
            actual.izq = eliminar(actual.izq, name);
        } else {
            Nodo aux = actual;
            if (aux.izq == null) {
                return aux.der;
            } else if (aux.der == null) {
                return aux.izq;
            } else {
                aux.info = reemplazar(aux);
            }
        }
    }
    return actual;
}

public void arbolCompleto(Nodo x) {
    if (x != null) {
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    }
}

public void preOrden(Nodo x) {
    if (x != null) {
        System.out.print(x.p.edad + "--");
        preOrden(x.izq);
        preOrden(x.der);
    }

}

public void inOrden(Nodo x) {
    if (x != null) {
        inOrden(x.izq);
        System.out.print(x.p.edad + "   ");
        inOrden(x.der);
    }
}

public void posOrden(Nodo x) {

    if (x != null) {
        posOrden(x.izq);
        posOrden(x.der);
        System.out.print(x.p.edad + "    ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tus problemas son en los métodos eliminar e inorder nada más?